# Unable to upload Captions file through YouTube API V3

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube API V3 and the [Google API PHP library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

I tried to upload the caption file as per their example which is at https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/captions.php.

I am getting the following error : (400) Failed to parse Content-Range header

Can somebody help me on this